# Select only numbers with hyphen between them and ignore any other chars

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have a scenario where I cannot control the input data, for example, my input can be

```
<phoneNumber>6504323957</phoneNumber>
```

or

```
<phoneNumber>650-432-3957</phoneNumber>
```

or

```
<phoneNumber>(650)432-3957</phoneNumber>
```

or

```
<phoneNumber>650.432.3957</phoneNumber>
```

however my output should always be like this

```
<areaCode>650</areaCode>
<phoneNumber>432-3957</phoneNumber>
```

I'm trying to achieve this using the following xsl, which works only for one condition not for other.

```
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:element name="areaCode">
<xsl:value-of select="substring(phoneNumber,1,3)"/>
</xsl:element>
<xsl:element name="phoneNumber">
<xsl:value-of select="substring(phoneNumber,5,12)"/>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="numbersonly" select="translate(phoneNumber, translate(phoneNumber,'0123456789',''), '')"/>
    <xsl:element name="areaCode">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring($numbersonly,1,3)"/>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="phoneNumber">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring($numbersonly,4,3)"/>-<xsl:value-of select="substring($numbersonly,7,4)"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

---

To handle input without area code you could use some simple math, and select from the right instead of from the left (*assuming a full phone is 10 digits*)..

```
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="numbersonly" select="translate(phoneNumber, translate(phoneNumber,'0123456789',''), '')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="length" select="string-length($numbersonly)"/>
    <xsl:element name="areaCode">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring($numbersonly,$length -9,3)"/>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="phoneNumber">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring($numbersonly,$length -6,3)"/>-<xsl:value-of select="substring($numbersonly,$length -3,4)"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Additional question, by keeping all my original conditions, how do we handle if incoming phoneNumber has missing areaCode, i.e

<phoneNumber>4323957</phoneNumber>

or 

<phoneNumber>432 3957</phoneNumber>

or

<phoneNumber>432-3957</phoneNumber>

then output should be

<areaCode/>
<phoneNumber>432-3957

Comment: @abhi, you can wrap an `<xsl:if test="not($numbersonly='')">` and `<xsl:if>` around the contents of the `phoneNumber` in the code..

Answer (score 2):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="phoneNumber">
  <xsl:variable name="vbareNum" select="translate(.,'-().','')"/>
  <areaCode><xsl:value-of select="substring($vbareNum,1,3)"/></areaCode>
  <phoneNumber>
   <xsl:value-of select=
   "concat(substring($vbareNum,4,3),'-',substring($vbareNum,7))"/>
  </phoneNumber>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document**:

```
<nums>
    <phoneNumber>6504323957</phoneNumber>
    <phoneNumber>650-432-3957</phoneNumber>
    <phoneNumber>(650)432-3957</phoneNumber>
    <phoneNumber>650.432.3957</phoneNumber>
</nums>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<areaCode>650</areaCode>
<phoneNumber>432-3957</phoneNumber>
<areaCode>650</areaCode>
<phoneNumber>432-3957</phoneNumber>
<areaCode>650</areaCode>
<phoneNumber>432-3957</phoneNumber>
<areaCode>650</areaCode>
<phoneNumber>432-3957</phoneNumber>
```

Comment: @Abhi, you are welcome. I think that there are only a limited number of punctuation characters in alternative presentations of a phone number, so it is more efficient to include them in a single `translate()` and thus avoid the double - translate.

Comment: @Abhi - It also wouldn't hurt to add a space to the translate just in case you get a phone number like `650 432 3957` or `(650) 432-3957`, etc. (`translate(.,'-(). ','')`)